# How can I copy a Pi image to a used Pi sd card? The disc imager telles me that the "old" Pi SD card is write protected

Tags: sd-card

I use a Pi 3 for development. Now I want to clone the SD card with my program to a Pi Zero W. I read out the image of the Pi 3 card with "disc imager", but cannot rewrite it onto the card that I used before in the Pi Zero.

Probably I have to remove the write prtection - but how?

Comment: Does this help [MicroSD Adapter Write Protect Switch](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6971/~/sandisk-microsd-memory-card-is-write-protected-or-locked)

Comment: Are you able to use another card reader?

Comment: also sometimes removing cards from a windows machine without "safely removing" sd cards they can go "write protected"

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the sd card storage when it pops up on your desktop and uncheck the write access box in the permissions section.

if you are using a mac, then use the terminal or the disk utility to erase the sd card first.